# How to Get Python Output in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I imagine this has been covered but after numerous searches I've been unable to find an answer.

I'm trying to write some Python code and would like to see the Output of that code, like I would in a Jupyter Notebook, except in VSCode. To be clear I'm not looking to replicate the IN: / OUT: cells of a Jupyter Notebook, just have all my Python Code in the code pane and it's output in the Output or Terminal Window.

For example if I run the following in Jupyter I see the contents of df, including the column names, the rows, info about the DF

```
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df
```

If I run that same code in VSCode it defaults to the terminal window and I don't see the df output even when clicking the output tab.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: They're entirely different paradigms. Just use `print(df)` when you're working with a standalone script.

Comment: Thanks for the reply AKX. There was an instance where that method didn't allow the output I needed, but I've since moved on from that "roadblock". I'll continue working and once I hit it again will update my example.

Comment: What do you mean by, "There was an instance where that method didn't allow the output I needed"? Was it a styling thing for a dataframe. Not a dataframe? By the way, you may have had issues finding the answer because you were searching using 'Jupyter'? 'IPython Notebook' pre-dated the Jupyter project and so sometimes the answer to basic issues, like how the last line of a `.ipynb` cell is special as Jupyter tries to always display what it returns & how you get that effect in pure Python, can be unearthed by including 'IPython Notebook' in place of 'Jupyter' in your search terms.

Comment: If it was dataframes you were wanting to display better in a text based console, there's [rich-dataframe](https://github.com/khuyentran1401/rich-dataframe) and [visidata](https://www.visidata.org/). (Use `visidata.vd.view_pandas(df)` for visidata.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the dataframe output, you can use the `Debug Console` tab in VSCode.

Assuming you have a python file with the contents shown in your description (the import and the `read_csv` line), here's how you you would do it:

1. Open the file in VSCode
2. Press F5 to debug the code and add a breakpoint after loading the csv.
3. You should be able to check the df contents by typing on the `Debug Console`

Check an example below:

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

To display text in a plain python file you need to use the print() function, unlike Jupyter Notebook where you can just call the variable name and it'll display the variable, so in this instance you need to change:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df
```

```py
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
print(df)
```

This new changed code uses the print function to display the value of the df variable.

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter and `.py` files are different file types. In Jupyter, the separate variable names output variable capacity, but in the `.py` script. You need to print the output with the `Print()` statement.

[image]

If you don't want to use the `Print()` statement, you can refer to the following method.

- Select code and then use **`Shift+Enter`** to open the interactive terminal and then execute the code

  [image]
- Use `Run in Interactive Window --> Run Current Fille in Interactive Window` function to execute code in the interactive window

  [image]